# Zend General Functionality

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter, frameworks

I am learning how to use the Zend Framework. I come from a codeigniter background.

What I want to do is define a function somewhere that performs a very simple yet useful function. I am predominantly going to use the function within view scripts. I don;t really want to make a whole class for such a simple thing, so my question is, is there anywhere were can I put a file containg all of my general functions and how do I go about using it?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are view helpers.
A view helper however is a function in a helper class. Therefore only one view helper can be put in a single class.

If you are using the project setup as used in the quick start tutorial or as generated by Zend_Tool, your view helpers should be put in the application/views/helpers directory.

Declaring a view helper is pretty simple, and is explained in great detail on this page of the zend framework documentation (i must say it's a bit hidden in the docs):
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom

Some background information on view helpers as well as some standard included ones can be found on this page: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html

Hope this helped you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar problem to this, that I couldnt fix. I defined a class called: class MY_View_Helper_Table extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract then tried this: $this->view->addHelperPath('', 'MY_View_Helper_Table'); and refered to it in the view using: $this->Table->hello(); But it just failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you realy whant to use a function you can make a library class with a static method , make a folder like this  Application/Library/MyLib , then at bootstrap register MyLib namespace like this

`$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
 $autoloader->registerNamespace('MyLib');` , then inside MyLib folder you can make a filename `MyClass` , with a class name `MyLib_MyClass` , then inside you're view you can call `MyLib_MyClass::staticMethod()`.

Tough i suggest you make a view helper for this . You don't realy use functions in ZF like you where used to in CI ( i was in you're exact situation a few months ago ) , ZF is all about OOP .